# How to write data structure Graph using Java model class

Tags: java, data-structures, object-graph

A product can have distinctive sorts of attributes, and they can change with regard to items, such as a car can have taking after qualities: {cost, colour, price} and chair can have : {cost, width, profundity, stature}. Product attributes are organized in a progressive bunch structure, where a product attribute group can contain one or a few product attributes and/or attributes. Group can contain one or a more Product Attributes and/or Product Attribute Groups.

Write the code required to handle the over portrayed items and a print work that prints the information in such a way that it is evident which properties have a place to which item and which quality gather in case any.

[image: Data Structure Image]

Comment: What have you coded?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Since one of your question tags is _data-structures_, I think a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) data structure may be appropriate.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This question was asked in one of the interview. Sorry to say this, I am also not clear that question. So I posted this to know the solution.